# How to make IB order LMT and GTC?

Tags: interactive-brokers

```
    order.m_orderType = 'LMT GTC'
```

doesn't work. I'm using IBpy but a java answer will be helpful too. 
I'm getting error message: 
ERROR:Quantstart:Server Error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the API manaul

> String m_tif   The time in force. Valid values are: DAY, GTC, IOC,
>   GTD.

```
    order = Order()
    order.m_orderType = 'LMT'
    order.m_tif = 'GTC'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Here's an API doc that needs to be updated. It lists GTC as an order_type thus the confusion:

Comment: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/tables/supported_order_types.htm

Comment: Very strange.  Maybe there's something or some order type I don't know about.

Comment: @Darian311: that link is broken now. Check [this one](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1Order.html#a6b82712a718127487631727db08f67d4)?